# "Test Not run" on VS2019 (Nunit)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9hJv.png)

While run the test it showing "Test not run" on visual studio 2019. I already install Nunit3test adaptor and required packages. Can anyone help me to sort it out?

I need to run the script without this warning

Comment: Can you try with individual test case, and see? FYI: Right click on test case and click run.

Comment: Please provide the minimum recurring example